# ¿Cómo hacer un rectángulo de asteriscos con función y adentro que usuario meta una palabra?

Tags: python

Código:

```
def carteldeasteriscos(cadena):
    cartel = ""
    cartel = cartel + "\n* " + cadena + " *\n"
    i = 0
    for i in range(i, len(cadena) + 5):
        cartel2 = cartel + i * "*"

    return cartel2

palabra = input("ingresa un nombre")
print("*" * len(palabra) + "****", carteldeasteriscos(palabra))
```

Answer (score 1):

Tu código funciona, pero es posible acortarlo:

```
def carteldeasteriscos(cadena):
    linea = '*' * (4 + len(cadena))
    return f'{linea}\n* {cadena} *\n{linea}'

palabra = input("ingresa un nombre: ")
print(carteldeasteriscos(palabra))
```

Answer (score 0):

no sé si entendí, pero si bien hay varias formas de resolver esto, me parece mejor poner print dentro de la función, por ejemplo:

```
def carteldeasteriscos(cadena):
    cadena =cadena.capitalize()
    largo = len(cadena)
    tope= "*"* (largo + 4)
    print(f"""\n{tope}
* {cadena} *
{tope}
""")

palabra=input("Ingresa un nombre: ")

carteldeasteriscos(palabra)
```

donde no agregué nada nuevo, salvo el método de cadenas capitalize() que devuelve la primer letra en mayúsculas, por lo del nombre.
Si te sirve el concepto le podés agregar el bucle donde lo necesites.